# putting negative sign when printing output

Tags: python, output, python-3.7, negative-number

I want a small suggestion. I was trying to write "negative", in front of my program's output if there is any any negative number in the input but could not do it. My code is given below:

```
def word(num):
   d1= {0:'Zero',1:'One',2:'Two',3:'Three',4:'Four',5:'Five',6:'Six',7:'Seven',8:'Eight',9:'Nine',10:'Ten',11:'Eleven',12:'Twelve',13:'Thirteen',14:'Fourteen',15:'Fifteen',16:'Sixteen',17:'Seventeen',18:'Eighteen',19:'Ninteen',20:'Twenty',30:'Thirty',40:'Fourty',50:'Fifty',60:'Sixty',70:'Seventy',80:'Eighty',90:'Ninty'}

   if (num<20):
      return d1[num]
   if (num<100):
      if num % 10 == 0:
         return d1[num]
      else:
         return d1[num // 10 * 10] + ' ' + d1[num % 10]
   if (num < 0):
      return "negative" + word(num)

print (word(-123))
```

When I am running this it is showing Traceback error (Key error: -123) .
What should I do to print :

negative one hundred twenty three?
Thank you.

Comment: is this python? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this is Python 3.7

Comment: in that case please accept the edit.

Comment: Yes, I edited the tag.